# How to export output text to a file

Tags: python

Updated question & code:

I have a PDF - Excel comparison programme which reads in approx 4 tables, then reads in an excel page and compares the elements within it.

I would like this output (in Ipython console using spyder) to save to a file.
I'm quite happy for this to print to a .txt file

The file has the comparison messages however the 'now comparing page..' 'now comparing part..' messages aren't being printed. (yesterday all the 'now comparing' messages were printed prior to the data matching messages but for some reason that's not happening anymore...)

I would like it to be of the format:

Now comparing page..

Now comparing part..

All data matches...

All data matches...

Now comparing part.. etc.

This is PART of a function which is in a different file which I call in my programme

```
def compare_pdf_with_excel(pdf_data, excel_data):
...
...
...    
f = open('testoutput.txt','a')
for n, col in enumerate(comparison.columns):
    if all(comparison[col]):
        f = open('testoutput.txt','a')
        s = 'Data matches for CDID {}!'.format(col)
        f.write(str(s))
        for row in comparison.index:
            if not comparison.loc[row][col]:
                f = open('testoutput.txt','a')
                s = 'Error - there is a mismatch for CDID "{}" in period "{}"!'\
                .format(col,row)
                f.write(str(s))
```

This is part of the code from my programme

```
f = open('testoutput.txt','a')
s = 'Now comparing PAGE ' + str(page_code) + ' page number ' + str(page_to_read)
f.write(str(s))
part_count = 0
for pdf, exc in zip([part_a1_1,part_a1_2,part_a1_3,part_a1_4], excel_chunks_a1_dropped):
    part_count += 1
    s = 'Now comparing part {}'.format(part_count)
    f.write(str(s))
    compare_pdf_with_excel(pdf, exc)
```

Comment: Post your code. If you are using `print()`, it has the `file` argument that will allow you to write to file, example: `print('Data matches...', file=open('out.txt', 'a'))`

Comment: My print() for the data matches/doesn't is within a function I have defined in a file which I call upon.
My print() for the page number and part is in the actual program itself. Would this be a problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: A single file for **all** pdf/exc comparisons or one file for each?

Comment: A single file with the whole list for every page, every part, every match/mismatch

Answer (score 0):

Accumulate all of the comparison result strings in a list then return the list when the function ends and write the results to a file all at once.

```
def compare_pdf_with_excel(pdf_data, excel_data):
    ....
    comparison.columns = columns
    results = []
    for n, col in enumerate(comparison.columns):
        if all(comparison[col]):
            s = 'Data matches for CDID {}!'.format(col)
            #print(s)
            results.append(s)
        for row in comparison.index:
            if not comparison.loc[row][col]:
                s = 'Error - there is a mismatch for CDID "{}" in period "{}"!'.format(col,row)
                #print(s)
                results.append(s)
    return results

for pdf, exc in zip([part_a1_1,part_a1_2,part_a1_3,part_a1_4],excel_chunks_a1_dropped):
    part_count += 1
    comparison_msg = 'Now comparing part {}'.format(part_count)
    print(comparison_msg)
    results = compare_pdf_with_excel(pdf, exc)
    results = ('\n'.join(results))
    print(results)
    with open(filepath, 'a') as f:
        f.write(comparison_msg = '\n')
        f.write(results)
```

---

`with open(filepath, 'a') as f:` will [open the file for appending](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) which means each time the function is called, it will append to a file if it already exists.  Adding a filepath parameter to your function gives you a bit more control.

Comment: Should note that if the function is called more than one (and the file is not deleted beforehand) the results of each run will continue to be appended to the file.

Comment: This is a great idea for the data messages but I also require it to capture the page / part messages (as in example in question)
Could I open the same file and write to that for the page/part messages?

Comment: Is there something instead of join? 
It comes up with TypeError: can only join an iterable

Comment: `results` should be a list which is iterable .  Do you return anything else from the function?  Print results before the *join*.  What is it?

Comment: It returns 'None'. I have defined compare_pdf_with_excel(pdf_data, excel_data) as a function. so does results=compare_pdf_with_excel(pdf,exc) give a function rather than the printed results? therefore its not a list? therefore not iterable?

Comment: I wrote my solution so that the function would return a lists of strings - `return results`. If you modified my solution and didn't explicitly return something, the function will return `None` (default *behaviour*)

Comment: copying your code with no modifications fails on line     results = ('\n'.join(results)) with TypeError: can only join an iterable.

I'll add my new code which does print to a file however in an incorrect order, perhaps you could help me modify that?

Thanks for your help

Comment: I don't know what to say. In the function an empty list is initially assigned to `results` so even if none of the subsequent conditions are True and nothing is appended to `results`, the function should return an empty list. An empty list will not produce the TypeError when used as an argument to `str.join()` - as written the function should not return `None` 
Your example only includes a portion of your function are there other return statements in your function that aren't in the example you provided?